# omniture tagging for mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagging, adobe-analytics

Is it possible to use omniture tagging for mobile sites? 
we have created site which can only be used on mobile and our client wants omniture tagging for the same site will it be possible,if yes what details we should have from client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most modern mobile devices (phones and tablets) can handle the [javascript implementation](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/dtm/) just fine. But if you want to be able to handle older mobile devices, the safest way to do it is to  [implement without javascript](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/#Implementing_Analytics_without_JavaScript). This method basically involves adding a static `img` tag to each page, pointing to a url with query params and static values. It can be made slightly more dynamic if you use server-side coding to dynamically output the `img` tag, but overall, you just won't get the same level of tracking/reporting from it, especially as far as any custom coding requirements that need to be done.